# Should questions about special effects techniques be allowed on Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, scope

I was wondering if questions about special effects techniques be allowed on the Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange?  For example, questions like

> What techniques did the artists use in the early ST:TNG episodes to create those alien world landscapes?

Answer (score 6):

I think yes, they should be allowed.  Also, in general, when it comes to 'should I ask X type of question', there's little to lose in asking it.  If it's not clearly laid out in the FAQ as being off-topic, the community will make its feelings known, and we can go from there.

(also the answer is [Matte painting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matte_painting))

Comment: Thanks for answering my example question, I always thought those landscapes looked awesome.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say no.

To use the same example: matte paintings are done for many productions that aren't SF/F—historical dramas, for instance. If you look at the matte painting article Keen linked, only about half of their examples count as SF/F.

The same goes for pretty much every other SFX technique (note: SFX stands for "[Special Effects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_effect)," not "Science Fiction").

I expect SFX questions will be completely on topic at [Video and Film Production](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2797/video-and-film-production)  when it launches. That proposal is currently in its commitment phase, so if this aspect interests you, go help out!

Comment: Asking about the production techniques (special effects, writing, publishing, whatever) of a specific work is on-topic, so long as the work is SF. Asking generic questions about production is off-topic unless they are intrinsically specific to SF.

Comment: I was assuming the question was talking about SFF works, given that the example was one.